# Paste Pictures and Organize

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following code, which sorts some pictures down according to a value in Sheet1. Horizontally the images are aligned in the required columns. But not in the Rows.

I tried to do it with another FOR loop that I called **J** but doesn't work, it puts the images on top of each other.

How can I align the pictures in a column and a row that I choose?

What am I doing wrong? or what am I missing?

Thank you.

-------------CODE-------------

```
Sub CommandButton2_Click()

Dim firma_pic As Picture
Dim pic_location As String
Dim identifier_pic As String

'For j = 14 To 23
'Next
'Worksheets("Sheet3").Cells(14, 23).Select

For i = 2 To 11
identifier_pic = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 11).Value
pic_location = "C:\Users\User\Downloads\Docs\img\" & Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 2).Value & ".png"

With Worksheets("Sheet3").Cells(i, 24)

Set firma_pic = ActiveSheet.Pictures.Insert(pic_location)
    firma_pic.Top = .Top
    firma_pic.Left = .Left
    firma_pic.ShapeRange.LockAspectRatio = msoFalse
    firma_pic.Placement = xlMoveAndSize
    firma_pic.ShapeRange.Width = 70
    firma_pic.ShapeRange.Height = 30
End With

Next
Worksheets("Sheet3").Cells(i, 23).Select

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Width and Height need to consider your cell too. You may resize images and force them to be W=70 and H=30 where the cell begins, but it could lead to images overlapping between columns. I'd suggest you to stick to the same workflow as you did for Top and Left

```
firma_pic.ShapeRange.Width = .Width
firma_pic.ShapeRange.Height = .Height
```